# Using Image Sizes for Custom Post Types outside the Loop

Tags: custom-post-types, post-thumbnails, images, thumbnails

I want to use an *image size* on a Custom Post Type (which has *featured image* enabled).

in `functions.php` I added:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
add_image_size( 'my-non-working-size', 600, 300, true );
```

The custom post type is called 'homeslide' as I use it to build a a carousel slider on home. To get all my slides I do :

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'   => 'homeslide'
);
$mypages = get_posts( $args );
```

I loop through the results and for every slide, I want to output the featured image in my custom size. This is my attempt:

```
the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, "my-non-working-size");
```

This doesn't work. It does output the featured images, but they are not  custom size, and they aren't cropped. Yet the same approach works within the theme's `while( have_posts() )` loop.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I was wrong about it outputting the featured images. It actually doesn't do anything. Although  `has_post_thumbnail( $page->ID )` returns `true` for every slide.

EDIT 3:

My whole code used for trying to display the featured images:

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type'   => 'homeslide'
    );
    $mypages = get_posts( $args );
    ?>
    <div class="your-class">
        <?php
        foreach( $mypages as $page ) {
            ?><div>
            <?php

            $content = $page->post_content;
            if ( ! $content ) // Check for empty page
                continue;

            ?>
            <h2><a href="<?php echo get_page_link( $page->ID ); ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></a></h2>
            <div class="entry"><?php
                if ( has_post_thumbnail( $page->ID )  ) {?>
                    <div class="col-left">
                       <?php the_post_thumbnail_url($page->ID , 'my-non-working-size'  ); ?>

                    </div><div class="col-right">
    <?php

    ?></div>
                    <?php
                }
                echo $content; ?></div>
    </div>
        <?php }  ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing wrong on this part

```
the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, "my-non-working-size");
```

For `the_post_thumbnail()` you don't need to pass post ID, you just have to pass size and attr. [More Info - the_post_thumbnail()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/#parameters)

So try like this `the_post_thumbnail("my-non-working-size");` without passing post ID.

Your markup messed up so I'm not sure your actual markup structure. Here is working example and It tested.

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type'   => 'homeslide'
);
$mypages = get_posts( $args );
?>
<div class="your-class container">
<?php
foreach ( $mypages as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
<div>
    <h2><a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <div class="entry">
        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
            <div class="col-left">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'my-non-working-size'  ); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-right">
            <?php // ?>
            </div>
        <?php
        } // end if has_post_thumbnail();
        the_content(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();?>
</div>
```

And please read this one if you want to need more about [get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts)

Comment: I think I do need to pass the ID in this case as I'm outside the loop. It doesn't work either way, no featured images are rendered.

Comment: Can you update your post with your code that you using to display thumbnail outside of the loop where `the_post_thumbnail()` your are using ?

Comment: Sure, just did it.

Comment: I'm also update my answer. and if you need different html markup feel free to do this. markup will not causing you any problem here.